# Cargar mas de un dato en una PILA

Tags: java, pilas

Estimados tengo una duda con este ejercicio, es decir, no logro comprender como trabajar estas PILAS, entiendo debería usar mas de dos, o se pueden cargar mas de un dato en cada elemento?
es decir por ejemplo pila[dni][nombre][dni conyuge], se que es básico pero estoy iniciando con JAVA.

Se tienen dos pilas, una de varones y otra de mujeres. De cada persona se
sabe el dni, el nombre y el dni del conyuge. Las pilas están ordenadas por
dni. Hacer una función que informe para cada varón cual es el nombre de su
mujer. Si la mujer no se encuentra informarlo. Si la mujer se encuentra pero
el dni del conyuge es otro informar "TRAMPA".

Comment: Al decir "Pilas" a que te refieres exactamente(? Quieres decir Arreglos o Matrices?

Comment: Puedes crear una clase `Persona` que tenga los atributos `dni`, `nombre`, y `dniConyuge`, y hacer pilas de `Persona`s

Comment: Cristi4n, te doy la bienvenida y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del 

sitio. Para realizar preguntas es importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la 

comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo!.

Comment: Gracias @DavidDPG, es Justo lo que necesito hacer, una "Pila de Objetos" estoy viendo como lo implemento.